# testing with rspec gives error: 'Please install the sqlite3 adapter' - railstutorial.org

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, railstutorial.org, sqlite3-ruby

Hi i got the same Problem like this guy: [Ruby Guard questions - 'Please install the sqlite3 adapter' - railstutorial.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958093/ruby-guard-questions-please-install-the-sqlite3-adapter-railstutorial-org/14799404#14799404)

Executing "bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb" gives me this:

```
C:\Users\Me\Ruby\sample_app>bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec
.rb
Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integrati
on.rb:147:in `block in replace_gem': Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem in
stall activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` (sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it t
o Gemfile.) (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_
record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active
_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active
_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active
_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active
_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_
record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:50:in `resolve_h
ash_connection'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_
record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:in `resolve_s
tring_connection'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_
record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:25:in `spec'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_
record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:130:in `establis
h_connection'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_
record/railtie.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active
_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active
_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active
_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active
_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active
_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_
record/base.rb:720:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-rails-2.11.0/lib/rspec/ra
ils/extensions/active_record/base.rb:19:in `<module:Extensions>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-rails-2.11.0/lib/rspec/ra
ils/extensions/active_record/base.rb:4:in `<module:Rails>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-rails-2.11.0/lib/rspec/ra
ils/extensions/active_record/base.rb:2:in `<module:RSpec>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-rails-2.11.0/lib/rspec/ra
ils/extensions/active_record/base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active
_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active
_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active
_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active
_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-rails-2.11.0/lib/rspec/ra
ils/extensions.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active
_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active
_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active
_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active
_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-rails-2.11.0/lib/rspec/ra
ils.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active
_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active
_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active
_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active
_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/Users/Ayhan/Ruby/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:4:in `<top (requ
ired)>'
        from C:/Users/Ayhan/Ruby/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1
:in `require'
        from C:/Users/Ayhan/Ruby/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:1
:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/cor
e/configuration.rb:780:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/cor
e/configuration.rb:780:in `block in load_spec_files'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/cor
e/configuration.rb:780:in `map'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/cor
e/configuration.rb:780:in `load_spec_files'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/cor
e/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/cor
e/runner.rb:69:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/cor
e/runner.rb:8:in `block in autorun'
```

But my database.yml looks like this:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  host: localhost
  username: user
  database: app-dev

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

What do i have to change in here?
Or is there another problem i cant see?

P.S: I installed postgreSQL, thats why i changed the development passage in the database.yml. And the gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
gem 'pg', '0.12.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

Answer (score 1):

With the current configuration in `config/database.yml`, development env is on `postgres` while `test` & `production` are using `sqlite3`. And there is no `sqlite3` gem included in the `Gemfile`. Hence the error message about `Please install the sqlite3 adapter`.

Why not use `postgres` for all of your environments instead of only for `development`?

Make the sections for `test` and `production` similar to that of `development` in `config/database.yml` with appropriate database names - `database: app-test` & database: app-prod` respectively.

Alternatively, if you want to use `sqlite3` for certain environments, include the `sqlite3` gem for that environment alone, and `pg` gem for the other environments.

**Example Gemfile config:**

The below config will include `pg` gem only for `production`, and `sqlite3` gem only for `development` & `test` environment.

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.11.0'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
end
```

Comment: Ok i changed it but now its not executing at all, just saying this:

Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.

I changed the database.yml like this: 

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: db/test
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  username: user

Comment: Please change both `test` and `production` appropriately, and run `bundle install` before running the `bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb` command.

Comment: Since you are changing the database config for environments, you will also have to create the databases with `rake db:create`.

Comment: What do you mean with changing them appropriately? The command doesnt start, i dont know why because there are no error messages now.
I thought it would be easier to use postgreSQL for all environments.
Changing the adapter name and the path to the database to db/development etc. didnt work :/

Comment: Okay, the rake db:create command doesnt execute as well... had to abort with strg+c

Comment: Doing rake db:create --trace shows that it gets stuck at "** Execute db:create" .... 
rake db:migrate doesnt do anything as well

Comment: Creating a postgres database is a bit complicated for a beginner - as Michael Hartl too mentions in the book; I would suggest working with `sqlite` for the time being, and get back to Postgres later. http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql?view=asciicast would be helpful at that time.

Comment: Yeah, i realized that and put the whole sqlite3 stuff back in. Now it works again